# How to change dateformat on Yii platform?

Tags: php, database, yii

I am new to the Yii platform, and I am wondering how to change the dateformat. It's currently in the American date format that is YYYY-MM-DD. I want it to be DD-MM-YYYY. Is there any way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config file add in 'components' => []
You can add it and edit it to your style.

```
'formatter' => [
    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    'datetimeFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
    'decimalSeparator' => ',',
    'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
],
```